# How can I prevent asp.net web api 2 from allowing html and scripts similar to MVC RequestValidation?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have content that is being entered into an API that is likely to appear on various websites. While these websites use CSP and other measures to help prevent XSS, I am looking for more solid input validation on my web api methods to validate better from the start.

What is considered the best practice to do this in web api? Can anyone recommend any resources to assist with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a HTML parser like [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/), then stripe unsafe tags and attributes like , or get only the innerText from the parser of choice.